# How to use i18n on angularjs 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, i18next

How I should use i18n so the variable "title" takes the value from the traslatated json. It should return "Mis viajes" and right now it is not returning anything. Thanks
trips-header.jade

I did this and I get "0" on the screen.

```
.trips-header
    .background-image
    .header-content
        p.title.ng-i18next {{   title | i18next}} 
        p.sub-title.ng-i18next {{   sub-title | i18next}}
```

Mi json

```
 {
  "es-AR": {
      "translation": {
         "title":"Mis Viajes!",
         "sub-title": " te ayuda a planificar y organizar tus viajes."
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you looked in the Internet? https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next

Comment: Yes! But I can't figure it out how to apply to a class. How can I do this?(use my example as a reference , thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample approach. You want html to look like this:

```
<h1>{{'hello' | i18next}}</h1>
```

Your jade is this:

```
- var foo = "{{hello | i18next}}"
h1= foo
```

Your translation is this:

```
{
  "es-AR": {
      "translation": {
          "hello":"hi!"
       }
    }
}
```

Your i18n in angular should be properly configured:

```
yourApp.config( ['$i18nextProvider',function( $i18nextProvider ) {
    $i18nextProvider.options = {
        lng: 'es-AR', //select or detect from browser
        useCookie: false,
        useLocalStorage: false,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        resGetPath:  l_prefix + 'locales/__lng__/__ns__.json',
        defaultLoadingValue: ''
    }
// file is expected to be locales/es-AR/translation.json
..... remaining of the config
```

EDIT: added quotes around the 'hello'. Now it is treated as a text and not a variable.

Comment: make sure that your angular side is correctly configured. inspect the elements in the dev tools. The html structure should be correctly rendered. Also, you might want to change sub-title into something that does not contain "-"

Comment: thanks man! I will check that out! By the moment I get 
i18next::translator: missingKey es-AR translation 0 0 on the dev tools

Comment: my bad. I have forgotten the quotes around 'hello. In the code. On top of that, make sure that translation strings are loaded by the time of rendering (since it is an async operation).